# javascript initial value of property function

Tags: javascript, node.js, initialization, commonjs, node-modules

foo.js

```
var bar = function () { return "hello world"; }

module.exports = {
  bar: bar
}
```

test.js

```
var foo = require("foo.js");

var greeting1 = foo.bar;
var greeting2 = foo.bar();
var greeting3 = foo.bar;
```

Do greeting1,greeting2,greeting3 all have value "hello world" in all cirumstances ?

Asking because what if there's a scenario where foo.bar initially is undefined because it hasn't been initialized and only initialized when foo.bar() is called.

Comment: In that code, `greeting1` and `greeting3` will be functions, not strings.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have two questions here.

> Do greeting1,greeting2,greeting3 all have value "hello world" in all cirumstances ?

Well, no, not quite. The `greeting1` and `greeting3` variables contain a function, `foo.bar`. Only `greeting2` contains the string, `"hello world"`. You have not acctually *called* the function in the other two cases, just referenced it and stored it in a variable.

> Asking because what if there's a scenario where foo.bar initially is undefined because it hasn't been initialized and only initialized when foo.bar() is called.

Node.js guarantees that `foo.bar` will be initialized by the time you use it. The `require` function is synchronous—it blocks until the requested module is loaded. Therefore, there is no need to worry about initialization, since Node will handle that for you.

Comment: That is not an answer to the question. He asked if property `bar` is "hello world" - and it isn't, because unless it is invoked it will point to the function. As you actually said in the comment... (?) You provide less (useful) information in the answer than in the comment :)

Comment: @Someone IMO, the question was unclear, and I commented on it that reflects that point. However, the final sentence seems to be asking the real question: "Asking because what if there's a scenario where foo.bar initially is undefined because it hasn't been initialized and only initialized when foo.bar() is called."

Comment: Yeah, but that only shows that OP is completely confused about how anything works (sorry OP), it seems - even more reason to provide the full explanation, no?

Comment: @Someone Fair enough; I've edited in some additional information to clarify.

Comment: Actually, reading that last sentence from OP again, how can `bar` be `undefined`, it should be a function if it's not been invoked yet... oh wait, no, it's just as I said - OP is confused, he's guessing not reporting an actual observation :) To OP: It won't be undefined, it will be a function or a string.

Answer (score 2):

`greeting1` and `greeting3` are functions (they both point to your `bar` function in the foo.js module).

Whereas `greeting2 === "hello world"` because it's the return result of executing that `bar` function.

This is because you're using `foo.bar` in some places and `foo.bar()` in others.  One just fetches the function, the one with `()` at the end actually executes the function.

---

To see the result in a simpler light, let's remove the module.  Your code is equivalent to this:

```
var foo = {
    bar: function() { return "hello world"; }
};

var greeting1 = foo.bar;     // contains a function reference
var greeting2 = foo.bar();   // contains "hello world" because it executed the function
var greeting3 = foo.bar;     // contains a function reference
```

---

The last sentence of your question is very confusing.  If `foo.bar` does not initially have a value (e.g. it's undefined), then you cannot execute `foo.bar()` until it does have a value.  Perhaps you need to show us the real code and how `foo.bar` is actually initialized.  In your question, it always has an initial value.

Comment: thanks jfriend00 i was erroneously thinking it possible that foo.js on load would execute the anonymous function and assign result to `var bar` and therefore `greeting1 = greeting2 = greeting3 = 'hello world'` ... but it seems that `var bar = function() {}` is the same thing as `function bar() {}`